# less.js guards and conditionals

Tags: css, conditional-statements, less, mixins

I have the following less mixin:

`@myColor = #123456;`

`.mixin(@a) when (@a = @myColor){
      // do something
    }`

This however throws this error: Unable to perform comparison

Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear (as of lesscss 1.2.2) that guards only support comparing Dimensions and Keywords. (search the source for "compare:") So, sadly, comparing two colors or strings just won't work.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**: Four thoughts (again, I don't have experience with LESS itself, I'm just looking at documentation).

1. Is the variable you are passing to the mixin (the `@a`) a color in hex format? Perhaps it cannot do the comparison because you are passing a different variable type.
2. Just to be sure, did you double check that you called the right variable (`@myColor`) not (`@mycolor`).
3. Have you tried reversing the `when` to `(@myColor = @a)` to see if that works. On the one example at http://lesscss.org/ where they use a variable not defined in the mixin (they use `@media`) that is the order they have it in.
4. Finally, my first original answer was to try:

   `.mixin(@a, @b: @myColor) when (@a = @b){ // do something }`

Answer (score 0):

Just update less.js to the last version (1.2.2 - current) and it will work.

I had the same problem. Now it fixed for me (My question with code example: [Lesscss Mixins with guards. Syntax Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9633415/lesscss-mixins-with-guards-syntax-error) ).
I think, it will be fixed and for your example.